# How to dynamically name an ECS cluster with cloudformation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Its easy to create the cluster `MyCluster` with a hardcoded name:

```
"MyCluster": {
  "Type": "AWS::ECS::Cluster"
}
```

However, I'm wanting to have a dynamic name but also reference the named resource. Something like this where the cluster name would be the stack name:

```
"NamedReferenceButNotClusterName": {
    "Type": "AWS::ECS::Cluster",
    "Properties": {
        "Name": {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}   <-- Name property isnt allowed
    }
},
"ecsService": {
    "Type": "AWS::ECS::Service",
    "DependsOn": [
        {"Ref": "NamedReferenceButNotClusterName"}  <-- not sure if I can even do this
    ],
    "Properties": {
        "Cluster": {
            "Ref": "NamedReferenceButNotClusterName"  <-- I really want this part
        },
        "DesiredCount": 2,
        "TaskDefinition": {
            "Ref": "EcsTask"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm not understanding the use case.  Why are you wanting to have a dynamic reference to a resource?  Those resource names are really just used like variable names.  So, it's like getting variables by reflection instead of just calling them by name.

Comment: Main reason is I want to provide the ECS cluster name as a parameter so a user running the template can call it whatever they want.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with AWS cloud formation.

`"MyCluster": {
  "Type": "AWS::ECS::Cluster"
}`

The above cloudformation script will generate a ECS cluster with name format `<StackName>-MyCluster-<RandomSequence>`.
The stackname is provided as input at the time of execution of the cloudformation script. The random sequence is generated by cloudformation and cannot be deterministic.

At this point the best bet to create a cluster with desired naming convention will be using aws cli or a small program using aws sdk.